# trouble with images

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode4.4, unrecognized-selector

I am having a problem during run-time that says

> -[__NSCFString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a86a80
>   2012-10-24 14:21:08.070 Diabetic Food Guide[767:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a86a80'

I think the problem lies in these parts of the code:

```
/*ViewControllerManual.m*/
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSDictionary* tier = (NSDictionary*)sender;
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loopbackSegue"]) {
        ViewControllerManual* nextController = segue.destinationViewController;
        nextController.items = [tier objectForKey:@"items"];
        nextController.title = [tier objectForKey:@"name"];
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"]) {
        DetailsController* nextController = segue.destinationViewController;
        nextController.name = [tier objectForKey:@"name"];
        nextController.foodPicture = [tier objectForKey:@"foodPicture"];
        nextController.tablePicture = [tier objectForKey:@"tablePicture"];
    }
}

/*DetailsController.m*/

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    nameLbl.text = self.name;
    foodPic.image = self.foodPicture;
    tablePic.image = self.tablePicture;
    }
```

foodPic and tablePic are both UIImageViews, and foodPic is set using `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"foodPicture"]];`
which calls from an array that contains the paths to the images. The error only occurs when loading a view of the class DetailsController.
If I need to supply more info, please don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: You are returning `NSString` at `[[self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"foodPicture"]`

Comment: I am confused then. The `NSString` contains the paths for the images so I am not setting the `nextController.foodPicture` as an image but as an `NSString`?

Comment: `[tier objectForKey:@"foodPicture"];` - returns `NSString`? then you should do this: `nextController.foodPicture = [UIImage named:[tier objectForKey:@"foodPicture"]];`

Comment: The same for `nextController.tablePicture`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're returning NSStrings here:

```
nextController.foodPicture = [tier objectForKey:@"foodPicture"];
nextController.tablePicture = [tier objectForKey:@"tablePicture"];
```

And then

```
// UIImage* = NSString*
nextController.foodPicture = [tier objectForKey:@"foodPicture"];
nextController.tablePicture = [tier objectForKey:@"tablePicture"];
```

Or you've over released something. But from your description it's more likely the issue with assigning NSString to an UIImage.